# How to replace a substring in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string

If there is an example phrase like,

> A guy named Rajesh Kumar Singh came to meet me yesterday.

I have to remove the name of "Secret agent" from this string, transforming the string like this:

> A guy named XXXX came to meet me yesterday.

I have the logic of identifying the name in string, I am stuck at the string manipulation, to remove word number 4,5,6 from the original string and replacing it with XXXX.

Comment: Would the input always start with `A guy named <some name>`, or are there other variations?  Also, can you include your current Python script in your question?

Comment: No, but the logic of finding the name is well in place. As mentioned in the problem, i need help with string manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Once we know the name to be replaced, then using replace method we can make it 
   
userText = "A guy named Rajesh Kumar Singh came to meet me yesterday."
name = "Rajesh Kumar Singh"
replacedName = "XXXXX YYYY ZZ"
userText.replace(name, replacedName)
'A guy named XXXXX YYYY ZZ came to meet me yesterday.'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the text would always start with the phrase `A guy named <some name>`, we can try using `re.sub` here as follows:

```py
inp = "A guy named Rajesh Kumar Singh came to meet me yesterday."
output = re.sub(r'^A guy named(?: [A-Z][a-z]*)+', 'A guy named XXXX', inp)
print(output)  # A guy named XXXX came to meet me yesterday.
```